# I need to print the values entered in an HTML form on the same page on submit

Tags: javascript, html

hotmailI need the values entered into the form to print out on the screen when submit is pressed. How do I do the Javascript to do this. I don't know where to start so please help!

Also does it look formatted correctly, I feel i am missing some things and that using tables to format was probably the wrong way of doing it.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
info = document.getElementById("personalInfo");
    info.innerHTML = "<strong>Peronal Info: </strong>" + "<br>" + "Name: " + 
                    document.feedback.fname.value +
                    " " +
                    document.feedback.lname.value +
                    "<br>" + "Email: " +
                    document.feedback.email.value;

info = document.getElementById("experienceSubmit");
    info.innerHTML = "<strong>Experience and Salary: </strong>" + "<br>" + "Years of experience: " + 
                    document.feedback.experience.value +
                    "<br>" + "Date of availability: " +
                    document.feedback.date.value +
                    "<br>" + "Compensation Chosen: " +
                    document.feedback.comp.value +
                    "<br>" + "Region Selected: " +
                    document.feedback.region.value;

info = document.getElementById("otherSubmit");
    info.innerHTML = "<strong>Other information: </strong>" + "<br>" + "# of References " + 
                    document.feedback.reference.value +
                    "<br>" + "Additional Comments: " +
                    document.feedback.comments.value; 
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body background="../Assignment 5/_images/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg" >
<form   name="feedback" method="post" onSubmit="return checkform()">
        <section  id="pinfo" class="inputArea">
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name: </td>
                    <td><input name="lname"
                               type="text"
                               autofocus
                               required
                               placeholder="lname"                               
                               size="25" />
                    </td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: </td>
                    <td><input name="fname"
                               type="text"
                               size="25"
                               required
                               placeholder="fname" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email: </td>
                    <td><input name="email"
                               type="email"
                               size="40"
                               required
                               placeholder="....@hotmail.com" />
                     </td>
                </tr>
                    <td>Gender: </td>
                    <td><select name="gender">
                            <option selected disabled style='display:none;'>
                            Gender</option>                         
                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                            <option value="Female">Female</option>                      
                        </select>

                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </fieldset>
</section>
<section id="experience">
            <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <label for="experience">Years of Experience: </label>
                    <input name="experience" type="number" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="date">Date</label>
                        <input name="date" type="date" />
                    </td>
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="comp">Compensation: </label><br>
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="Salary" value="Salary Selected">Salary &nbsp;
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="SalaryWB" value="Salary with bonus Selected">Salary with Bonus &nbsp;
                        <input name="comp" type="radio" id="Commission" value="Commission Selected">Commission &nbsp;
                    </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="region">Region: </label><br>
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="East" value="East Selected">East &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="West" value="West Selected">West &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="North" value="North Selected">North &nbsp;
                    <input name="region" type="checkbox" id="South" value="South Selected">South &nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          </fieldset>
</section>
<section id="other">
<fieldset>
          <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <label for="reference">References<br>0&nbsp;&nbsp 1 &nbsp;&nbsp 2 &nbsp&nbsp 3 &nbsp&nbsp 4 &nbsp&nbsp 5<br></label>
            <input name="reference" id="reference"
                    type="range" 
                    value="0"
                    min="0"
                    max="5"
                    step="1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="comments">Additional Comments: <br></label>
                    <textarea 
                    name="comments"
                    rows="5" 
                    cols="20" 
                    placeholder="Please include any other pertinent information here"></textarea>                   </td>
            </tr>          
          </table>          
</fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</section>
</form>
<section id="personalInfo"></section>
<section id="experienceSubmit"></section>
<section id="otherSubmit"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: Should we assume you want to do so only when the data is invalid? If you allow a successful submit then you are essentially reloading the page and would need to read the post data.

Comment: Not for this particular page, I need to print all the values entered.

Comment: You will have to use a server side language such as PHP or equivalent because a submit sends the form data to server and returns a new page. AJAX would be an exception but I believe that would fall outside of your scope

Comment: Just edited the scripting. I can see the values pop-up but dissapear soon after.

Comment: @user278153 use form action like ...action="#" .....

Comment: @user278153 in javascript code not returning false bcoz your of error in namming....<section id="outregion"></section> ...change it to outRegion......R should be capital ..........

Comment: I changed the code, I no longer have the outRegion. I found a shorter way of doing it. The radio button, "comp" and the checkbox, "region" don't print their values. They print undefined instead.

Comment: Everything else prints fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in onsubmit checkform() function do the codding of printing values...

like...

```
<script>
    function checkform()
    {
         document.getElementById("outL").innerHTML=feedback.lname.value;
        //like this you can do for all field
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @user278153 Welcome.......have you got your answer?? if yes then plz mark it as a answer...

Comment: No, when i do this, the values pop up for a second and then dissapear, how can I make them stay on the screen?

Comment: @user278153 in javascript code not returning false bcoz your of error in namming....<section id="outregion"></section> ...change it to outRegion......R should be capital ..........

Answer (score -1):

i have created sample for you. please check below code

```
$("#feedback").submit(function(e){
    alert("hi");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/f9wRU/4/)

Comment: This answer assumes he is using the jQuery library